# Swift iOS custom cell properties can't be changed (unwrap empty optional)

Tags: ios, swift

I have gone through all the questions regarding this matter that seems to be popular. Anyhow, I have created a simple app with a table view that uses custom cells. 
I use the storyBoard, and defined the cells with the same name the class I created, Xcode even auto-completed me. 
Though when I initialise a new cell, I can't change the properties of the labels and image contained in the cell. I receive an error saying I accessed a nil, and I kinda get it. Though I couldn't seem to find a way around it. Can someone help?

```
import UIKit

class ExtenderCell: UITableViewCell {

@IBOutlet var main_image: UIImageView! 
@IBOutlet var name_label: UILabel! 
@IBOutlet var desc_label: UILabel!

init(to_put_image: UIImage, name: String, desc:String){
    super.init(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Subtitle, reuseIdentifier: "cell")
    name_label.text = name
    desc_label.text = desc
    main_image.image = to_put_image
}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using `storyBoard` for cell creation with `outlets`.**Your `outlets` are not accessible to you till `awakeForNib()` using `storyBoard` as it is not unarchived till `awakeFromNib`.** Your `outlets or properties` are nil in `init` so you are getting this exception as you are trying to `unwrap nil outlet property` in `init` method.

As your `outlet properties` are not accessible in `init` method and they are nil in `init`.So you need to set your `outlets` in `awakeForNib()`.Or you can set the properties in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`.So best approach is to make your `init` method as `instance method` if you want to use `storyBoard`.

```
import UIKit

class ExtenderCell: UITableViewCell {

@IBOutlet var main_image: UIImageView! 
@IBOutlet var name_label: UILabel! 
@IBOutlet var desc_label: UILabel!

func setContents(to_put_image: UIImage, name: String, desc:String){

    name_label.text = name
    desc_label.text = desc
    main_image.image = to_put_image
}
}
```

set the contents of cell in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
      //Check your identifier in storyBoard is "cell"
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as ExtendedCell 
    cell.setContents(yourImage, name: yourName, desc: yourDescription)

    return cell
}
```